# Scraping dynamically rendered links from an infinite scrollbar in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, casperjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to scrape the links on the left sidebar of [this page](http://www.super-resume.com/ResumeBuilder.jtp?query=Web%20Developer) using CasperJS.

The page has hundreds of links in the sidebar, but only loads 20 at a time when you scroll down. This code successfully grabs the first 20 (needs casperjs and phantomjs globally installed to run):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
// helper function that gets all of the resume links on the page:

  var getAllLinks = function() {
    var linksOnThisPage = []
    $("a[href^='/ResumeB']").each(function(index, linkDiv) {
      $linkDiv = $(linkDiv)
      linksOnThisPage.push('http://www.super-resume.com' + $linkDiv.attr('href'))
    });
   return linksOnThisPage
  };

//start casper, go  to page, run helper function:
casper.start('http://www.super-resume.com/ResumeBuilder.jtp?query=Database+Administrator', function() {
  allLinks=casper.evaluate(getAllLinks)
  console.log('number of links found:', allLinks.length);
});

casper.run();
```

I can make the page scroll down in the actual browser with this:

```
$('#search-left-inner').scrollTop(10000);
```

10000 is an arbitrarily big number; every time you run that code in the browser, it loads 20 more links. (Ideally I'd like to be able to grab all at once without having to keep reloading 20 at a time, but that's less pressing for now.) 
If I put that line inside the `getAllLinks` function like so:

```
var getAllLinks = function() {
    $('#search-left-inner').scrollTop(10000);

    var linksOnThisPage = []
    //etc, etc,
```

it still only loads 20 links. Many similar posts discuss synchronicity issues, so I've I've tried to get the it to wait for the sidebar to finish loading a few ways, including this:

```
var getAllLinks = function() {
    casper.then(function () {
        $('#search-left-inner').scrollTop(100000);
    });
    casper.then(function () {

    var linksOnThisPage = []
    //etc. etc.
}
```

but now for some reason it only finds one link instead of 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that if you scroll, it doesn't immediately load the next items, because loading takes time. You need to wait a little after scrolling before you can attempt to scrape all of the elements again.

```
casper.start(url)
    .thenEvaluate(scroll)
    .wait(5000, function(){
        var links = this.evaluate(getAllLinks);
        this.echo(links.length);
    })
    .run();
```

If this produces more links, then you can try the next step and that is infinite scrolling until no new elements are loaded. This can be done with asynchronous recursion in CasperJS:

```
var linkCount = -1;

function getAllLinks() {
    var linksOnThisPage = []
    $("a[href^='/ResumeB']").each(function(index, linkDiv) {
        $linkDiv = $(linkDiv)
        linksOnThisPage.push('http://www.super-resume.com' +   $linkDiv.attr('href'))
    });
    return linksOnThisPage
}

function scroll() {
    $('#search-left-inner').scrollTop(10000);
}

/**
 * Returns true if more elements were loaded that were before
 */
function checkMore(){
    var newLinks = this.evaluate(getAllLinks);
    var newCount = newLinks.length;
    if (linkCount === -1) {
        linkCount = newCount;
    }
    return linkCount < newCount
}

/**
 * Executes the a single iteration step and waits for a change in numbers.
 * Terminates if there are no changes in 6 seconds.
 */
function step(){
    this.thenEvaluate(scroll)
        .waitFor(check, step, function _onTimeout(){
            var links = this.evaluate(getAllLinks);
            this.echo("finished with " + links.length + " links\n\n"+links.join("\n"));
        }, 6000);
}

casper.start(url, step).run();
```

Keep in mind that it makes only sense to use jQuery in the DOM context (page context) which is inside of [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate). I suggest that you also read the [PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) of that function.